# Long-distance collaboration as Master student

Tags: thesis, masters, internship

I am about to start a Master's degree in Computational Biology. My future goal is to do a Ph.D. in Europe in the field of Computational Biomedicine. I have already completed the first year of another Master's degree an I have some research experience since I was allowed to work as a Student Assistant in a research group at that University and I carried out some small research projects during the last semester (final projects for some courses). Since I would like to continue doing research also at the new University and since I would really love to find a nice supervisor for my future studies, I am trying to find a project I can work on.

The big problem is that I found a nice group in Germany (I will study in Italy) and I am pretty sure it would be a nice place for my Ph.D. The question is: do you think it would be possible for me to work on one of their project while I am studying in another country? I was thinking about something like the following: contacting them in order to see if this is feasible, start studying what I would need, and then start the project that I will continue also for my Master's thesis. Are you aware of any *long-distance* student project experience? Is it better not to contact them at all and wait until I start the internship for my thesis? Any feed-back is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this kind of thing is possible. My Master's thesis was supervised remotely, although myself and my supervisor were both in the same country, just at different universities. The one piece of advice I would give is contact them through email well in advance, Skype them as soon as you can if they agree to the project and try to meet them in person at some point near the beginning of the project too. While electronic communication is sufficient, nothing beats face to face discussions.